# How to set inputs in vhdl (ISE Design Suite) without a testbench?

Tags: vhdl

I want to quickly test something without having to go through the long process of creating a testbench. Is there any way in which I can just simply change the input of A from "UUUU" to "0111", for example?

Comment: Before you keep downvoting me, yes I have searched for answers before posting and there simply aren't. I will be evaluated and I won't have time to create a testbench during the exam, and I'm sure there must be an easy way to do this but I can't figure it out

Comment: There will be something proprietary that your simulator will do, but I very much doubt it would be quicker than dong a very simple testbench - literally five minutes work, frankly.

Comment: Time taken to type in and run this [testbench](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/32yb) from scratch - 3:30 - including wasting 45s debugging some issue with EDA Playground (It seemed to think it was simulating SystemVerilog for some reason).

Comment: And it gets faster after three, four test benches as I tend to copy-paste standard sections like generating clock(s) and reset.

Comment: Right-click on the signal in waveform window and you'll find a `Force constant` option. It is easy to do this for one or two signals. As the design grows, it gets more and more time-consuming and difficult. Writing a testbench is the right way. It is beneficial as pointed out by earlier comments. Moreover, with ISE, you can also generate a template testbench specifically for the entity/component you want to test. Tool will generate a nice template. You only have to add stimuli and correct your clock and reset port-names. It doesn't get easier than that.!

Answer (score 0):

Add default port values like in

```
entity foo is
    port (
        bar1    : in  std_logic := '0';
        bar2    : out std_logic := '0'
    );
end entity foo;
```

Else forcing the value in the simulator works fine, as commented